# C# Change Form1 Width with data from Form 2

Tags: c#, forms

I've been breaking my head over a problem I have (I just started coding in C#)

I have a Main Screen (Hereafter reffered to as Form 1) and a Video Options Form (hereafter reffered to as Form 2) (Picture Included). Now, when f.e. I change the Radiobuttons in Form 2 to "*Windowed*" and Select a Resolution, I want some options to change in Form 1.

This is as far as I got so far, it goes to the Form 1 code, but says I can't change anything there.

Code Snippet Main Form

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visual_Options options = new Visual_Options();
        options.Show();
    }
```

Code Snippet Options Form

```
public partial class Visual_Options : Form
{
    frmMain Main;

    public Visual_Options()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Visual_Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Main.FormBorderStyle) //Check the Borderstyle of frmMain with Switch to determine current state
        {
            case FormBorderStyle.None: // if BorderStyle of frmMain = "None"
                if (Main.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) //Check if frmMain = Maximizes
                {
                    rbFullscrn.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rbBorderless.Checked = true;
                };
                break;
            case FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D:
                rbWindow.Checked = true;
                break;
        }

        switch (Main.Width) //Check Width to determine current value
        {
            case 800:
                rb8x6.Checked = true;
                break;
            case 1024:
                rb10x7.Checked = true;
                break;
            case 1280:
                rb12x7.Checked = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbFullscrn.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        }
        else if (rbBorderless.Checked == true && rb8x6.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Main.Height = 600;
            Main.Width = 800;
        }
        else if (rbBorderless.Checked == true && rb10x7.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Main.Height = 768;
            Main.Width = 1024;
        }
        else if (rbBorderless.Checked == true && rb12x7.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Main.Height = 720;
            Main.Width = 1280;
        }
        else if (rbWindow.Checked == true && rb8x6.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Main.Height = 600;
            Main.Width = 800;
        }
        else if (rbWindow.Checked == true && rb10x7.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Main.Height = 768;
            Main.Width = 1024;
        }
        else if (rbWindow.Checked == true && rb12x7.Checked == true)
        {
            Main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Main.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Main.Height = 720;
            Main.Width = 1280;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I've looked on the internet for a bit now, and, I found a few solutions, but, from the few solutions I found, none seemed to work so far.

Ty in advance,

Me ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you use ShowDialog, it will open your options Form as a Modal Dialog, that way once you make changes you can check the `DialogResult` and read a Public Property from your Option Form in your Main Form, using it to set your size. Otherwise you could subscribe to the Options Form's Closed Event and use that event to set your Forms Size.

Fist Option:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visual_Options options = new Visual_Options();
    if ( options.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        this.Size = options.getFormSize;  //This is a public property returning a size
}
```

2nd Option using same property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visual_Options options = new Visual_Options();
    options.FormClosed+=new FormClosedEventHandler(options_FormClosed);
    options.Show();
}

void options_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = ((Visual_Options)sender).getFormSize;
    ((Visual_Options)sender).FormClosed -= new FormClosedEventHandler(options_FormClosed); //Remove handler to prevent leaks
}
```

Comment: +1 This is known as the 'owner/owned form' relationship, for those interested in diving in a bit deeper. I only throw this in for beginners because I know how much confusion surrounds this issue. 
>>>I cannot recommend this book enough for Jr. level and below.<<<[Windows Forms Programming 2.0](http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Programming-Microsoft-Development-Series/dp/0321267966/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359785240&sr=8-1&keywords=windows+forms)

Comment: Ty for the quick replies, really appreciate it.

Buw, I tried both solutions you offered me Mark, but, Both of them gave me an error at the "getFormSize". Am I maybe in need of a *"Using"* to make it work?

Comment: @Shadowcreep. The  getFormSize is a custom property that you have to add to your options form.

Comment: @Mark ohyeah, my bad, should've thought about that haha ty

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this:

`options.Show(this);` passing the `this` reference will make "options" form as the child of your mainform.

Then `frmMain Main` can be set as:

```
frmMain Main = (frmMain)this.Owner;
```

After this, you can alter any and all properties of your main form.